# How select rows in ASCII file in python

Tags: python, file, select, row, ascii

I have an ASCII (a TEX file) with several columns of numbers. The last column has a flag 'a' or 'r'. I want to plot one column vs another column with different symbol depending the flag is 'a' or 'r'.

The TEX ascii file looks like that (with out the header):

```
0.99 & 0.00 & 5.9 & 0.0 & 180  & 13  & 1 & a \\
3.27 & 0.00 & 19.4 & 0.0 & 148 & 13  & 1 & r \\
```

I read the TEX file using np.loadtxt

```
dtype1 = np.dtype([('x', np.float), ('a', np.float), ('b', np.float), ('c', np.float), ('d', '|S1')])

x,a,b,c,d = np.loadtxt('arquive.tex', skiprows=7, usecols=(0,2,4,5,7), dtype=dtype1, unpack=True, delimiter='&', comments='\\' )
```

I would like to plot the column 'b' vs the column 'x' with different symbols depending that the flag is 'a' or 'r'.
Thanks for your help